# macro word "VBA error too many line continuations"

Tags: arrays, vba, variant

I have a long variant array. I was trying to break it with (, _) but I still got the same error.

for example:

```
arr as variant 
arr = array(15,54,10,15,0,0,0,51,12,36,23,15,52,115,132,16,13,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,51,13, _,
            ,1,25,15,31,81,35,64,31,,0,0,0,0,2,0,5,1,4,3,150,1,91,156,151,51,150,1,0,0,0, _ , ...
```

maybe the array length is 30 lines.

any help on how to solve this error?

Comment: There is probably a better solution for this. Why do you need an array like this? Where are those numbers coming from? Keep in mind that VBA does have limitations on things, and if you are running up against one, you are probably not using the best solution.

Comment: if my values are a string, i can break them with some good scripts to make the string into 255 long. but this is not a string and I want a way to solve this issue if you have some good ideas

Comment: Could you share the complete thing if it's only 30 or so lines?

Comment: @vbasic2008 i mean just the array 30 lines m not the full code.

Comment: Where are those numbers coming from?

Comment: While this is a horrible practice and almost certainly accomplished in a much better manner, if you are simply trying to break the code into separate lines for readability get rid of the commas after the '_' character.

Comment: @JodyHighroller there is still a limit to the number of lines that can be continued.

Comment: @braX those numbers are bytes, and they should be in the array. Can't separate them and I'm trying to solve this error

Comment: ok, they are bytes, coming from where? a database? a spreadsheet? an external file?

Comment: @braX it is generated from a tool, maybe i can save this byte in an external file and read it from vba?  I'm still new to vba environment

Comment: That may not be the perfect solution, but it's going to be a better one than trying to do it this way.

Comment: what are you suggesting for this situation? do you have a better idea to bypass the limitation?  @braX

Comment: There is no way around the limitation that you ran up against. You need to read the values into the array some other way, as you just said, read it from an external file maybe. You need a different approach.

Comment: Even if there would be no line continuation limit I would *never* paste these values into the code! Is this Excel-VBA-Code? Why not paste the data on a sheet and then read them into an array via VBA? Then - if the values change - anybody can paste them again on the sheet and has no need for coding knowledge.

Comment: @ike this is not excel-vba code

Comment: Propably you should enhance your question to describe the overall requirement you have to solve. Then it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you take your data another way? or do you need to generate random numbers? I think it will take more explanation on what you plan to do to help yourself.

So far the only thing I have found is that your array is filled with a function. I don't know if that will satisfy you as an answer.

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Array(15, 54)
    
    Call AddArray(arr, Array(15, 54, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, 51, 12, 36, 23, 15, 52, 115, 132, 16, 13, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 51, 13))
    Call AddArray(arr, Array(1, 25, 15, 31, 81, 35, 64, 31, , 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 1, 4, 3, 150, 1, 91, 156, 151, 51, 150, 1, 0, 0, 0))
End Sub

Function AddArray(ByRef arr As Variant, ByRef arrAdd As Variant) As Variant
    ' "UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1" : Is the calcul for get length of array
    LengthArr = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
    LengthArrAdd = UBound(arrAdd) - LBound(arrAdd) + 1
    
    'Calcul the length of futur array
    LengthNewArr = LengthArr + LengthArrAdd - 1
    
    'Redimension the arr
    ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To LengthNewArr)
    
    'Fill the arr with i who start to new espace of array at end
    For i = LengthArr To LengthNewArr
        arr(i) = arrAdd(i - LengthArr)
    Next
    
    'AddArray = arr
End Function
```

result : arr(0) = 15, arr(1) = 54, ..., ..., arr(59) = 0, arr(60) = 0